# ffprobe failed to execute command

Tags: php, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

I'm trying to get a frame from a video in a temp location but I get an error like this:

```
Uncaught Alchemy\BinaryDriver\Exception\ExecutionFailureException: ffprobe failed to execute command '/usr/bin/ffprobe' '/tmp/phpfwEh9u'
```

Which is weird because I have another script that does the exact same thing but there is no error. Are there any reasons for why this could be happening? Could there be any factors causing this in my script:

```
$sec = 1;
$movie =  $filentmpname;
$thumbnail = 'thumbnail_uploads/' . $imfileid;

$ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create();
$video = $ffmpeg->open($movie);
$frame = $video->frame(FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds($sec));
$frame->save($thumbnail);
```

Comment: Sometimes its a permission denied in the temp directory or ffprobe encounted an internal exception on the media file being converted